Is it possible to pass data from the View Hieracrchy to the App Delegate without using a Singleton?
I want to access data that is populated into Environment Objects during the lifetime of my application in my AppDelegate's applicationWillTerminate() function.
I've looked around Stack Overflow and elsewhere and the only pattern that seems viable is a gobally accessible variable.
Is there another way to get data from the EnviromentObject into the App Delegate function?
I guess I'd be open to aquiring the data in life cycle functions before applicationWillTerminate() if that's an option. I haven't done that, it would require a fair amount of restructuring, but I'll definitely do it if that is suggested.
Regardless, is there another way to do this? I see other scenarios in which this might be useful.

Are you you using the SwiftUI lifecycle?

Service Locator

Looks like an XY problem. Maybe share what are you trying to solve by sending data to applicationWillTerminate

I am not sure what you technically mean @jnpdx. I will say yes. I am using the App Delegate lifecycle functions and the View's lifecycle functions like OnAppear(). How would this affect the original question?

I am just trying to get ahold of a UUID to make an API Call once the app closes. Perhaps this is an XY problem. I was quite general in my explanation I must say @timbretimbre

In order to know how to provide an example, it would be helpful to know whether you're using the SwiftUI lifecycle with an AppDelegate adaptor. Googling "SwiftUI lifecycle" will show you what that means.
